# uwp make commandbar not float

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Below is a simplified version my page. I want to put a `MultiSelectCommandBar` (a custom `UserControl` of `CommandBar`) below the `Frame` of the `NavigationView`. However, as you can see from the image I posted below, the command bar (with a red arrow aside) is floating above the `Frame`. I want the `Frame` and the `MultiSelectCommandBar` on the same level, so that it will neither block the content of the frame nor block the `InAppNotification` in my page.

How can I do that?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <NavigationView
        x:Name="MainNavigationView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
        IsBackEnabled="True"
        ItemInvoked="MainNavigationView_ItemInvoked"
        PaneClosing="MainNavigationView_PaneClosing"
        PaneOpening="MainNavigationView_PaneOpening"
        Style="{StaticResource MainNavigationViewStyle}"
        TabNavigation="Cycle">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame
                x:Name="NaviFrame"
                IsNavigationStackEnabled="True"
                Navigated="NaviFrame_Navigated" />
            <--- Problem below！！！ --->
            <localControls:MultiSelectCommandBar x:Name="BottomMultiSelectCommandBar" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </NavigationView>
    <Grid
        x:Name="AppTitleBar"
        Height="32"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="Transparent">
        <Border
            x:Name="AppTitleBorder"
            Width="{x:Bind MainNavigationView.OpenPaneLength, Mode=OneWay}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Transparent" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="AppTitle"
            x:Uid="AppTitle"
            Height="{x:Bind AppTitleBar.Height, Mode=OneWay}"
            Padding="10,8"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
            Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="BackButton"
        x:Uid="BackButton"
        Background="Transparent"
        Click="BackButton_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Button
        x:Name="FakeTogglePaneButton"
        Grid.Row="1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="{StaticResource MinimalTitleBarColor}"
        Click="FakeTogglePaneButton_Click"
        Visibility="Collapsed">
    </Button>
    <local:MediaControl
        x:Name="MainMediaControl"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Mode="Main" />
    <local:LoadingControl
        x:Name="MainLoadingControl"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        AllowBreak="True"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <controls:InAppNotification
        x:Name="ShowResultInAppNotification"
        Grid.Row="1"
        AnimationDuration="0:0:0.1"
        HorizontalOffset="0"
        ShowDismissButton="True"
        StackMode="Replace"
        VerticalOffset="100" />
    <controls:InAppNotification
        x:Name="UndoInAppNotification"
        Grid.Row="1"
        AnimationDuration="00:00:00.1"
        HorizontalOffset="0"
        StackMode="Replace"
        VerticalOffset="100">
    </controls:InAppNotification>
</Grid>
```

[image]

This is my project [website](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer). My posted code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/MainPage.xaml). MultiSelectCommandBar is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/MultiSelectCommandBar.xaml).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Canvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas?view=winrt-19041) as root container, and set the same ZIndex for children element to keep them on the same level. But for your case, we suggest add new method for your `IMultiSelectListener interface` and cut the playlist height when `MultiSelectCommandBar` was shown and recover playlist height when `MultiSelectCommandBar` hidden.

Comment: Can you specify on "cut the playlist height"?

Comment: You could use visual tree helper to get playlist's height and edit it.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew I have check the CommandBar's height at the run time, which gives me NaN. I don't know how much should I edit.

Comment: What about actual height value?

Comment: I got 0 for ActualHeight. @CoCaIceDew

Comment: Ok, fine, have you tried use `RenderTransform` to set TranslateY value with negative value that could make your Playlist content move up when commandbar was show.

Comment: I think the problem is more like `MultiSelectCommandBar` has `Grid.Row=0`  instead of `Grid.Row=1`

Comment: Ok, cool, please go ahead post your answer below.